# Can I check if WooCommerce product is subscription?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I found some solutions but non of them seem to work.

```
  <?php if ( get_post_type() == 'product') : ?>
```

Since both Subscription and Single product are type of product, is there a way to ask which product type they are?

Answer (score 0):

Woo can do!

```
$product->is_type( $type )
```